# Find all values of a for which the following system has a solution, no solution and infinitely many solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

Find all values of a for which the following system
$$\begin{cases}x+2y+z=a^2 
\\x+y+3z=a
\\3x+4y+8z=8\end{cases}$$

has a solution, no solution and infinitely many solution.

I found the reduced row echelon form of this system which is:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 4a^2+12a-40\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -a^2-5a+16\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -a^2-2a+8
\end{pmatrix}$

Does that mean this system has only one solution and there is no value for a which makes the system infinitely many solutions and no solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes since the RREF is the following

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 &a^2\\
1 & 1 & 3 & a\\
3 & 4 & 8 & 8
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 &a^2\\
0 & 1 & -2 & a^2-a\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 8-2a-a^2
\end{pmatrix}$$

by [Rouché–Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem), we always have exacty one soution for the system.

Answer (score 1):

The system of equation if written as $AX=B$, then $\det|A|=-1 \ne 0$. so this system will have a unique solution for any value of $a$.

Comment: We didn't learn about determinants yet, so I can't make use of this.